# Creating private packages for a group of files in a project

Tags: actionscript-3

How can i create a private package for a group of files in an Actionscript project ? 
Let's say, I have pack2, so that they are accessible only by pack1.Class_A and pack1.Class_B.  pack2 MUST NOT BE ACCESSIBLE by app.Class_A or app.Class_B  :

src

1. app

   1.1-Class_A

   1.2-Class_B
2. pack1

   2.1-Class_A

   2.2-Class_B

   2.3-pack2

   2.3.1 -Class_C

coded Class_C as follows :

```
package pack2  // <<<< NOTE, IT's NOT pack1.pack2 
{
    public class Class_C
    {
        public function Class_C()
       {

       }

     } 

}
```

But this doesnot solve my purpose, as i see Class_C is still accessible by app.Class_A and app.Class_B  by using pack2.Class_C

How can i make pack2.Class_C private for pack1.Class_A and pack1_ClassB

Answer (score 1):

Put these classes you need to reach from pack1 into pack1, mark them internal, that's all.